# Why does a high order generic function erases falsy types from the returned function arguments?

Tags: typescript

Take for example this generic [Decorator Factory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories) Factory - a Factory that builds Decorator Factories for defining form metadata:

```js
interface FormFieldOptions {
  name?: string;
  label?: string;
  format?: string;
}

type FormProperties = Record<string | symbol, FormFieldOptions>;

function FormFieldPropertyDecorator<K extends keyof FormFieldOptions>(
  option: K,
  defaultValue?: FormFieldOptions[K] | 'propertyKey',
) {
  return function FormFieldProperty(value: FormFieldOptions[K] | null) {
    return function (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) {
      // ... Some reflect-metadata magic ...
    };
  };
}
```

The type `value: FormFieldOptions[K] | null` is coerced to just `value: FormFieldOptions[K]` when instantiating the Decorator Factories:

```js
// const FormField: (value: string) => (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void
export const FormField = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('name', 'propertyKey');
// const Label: (value: string) => (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void
export const Label = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('label');
// const Format: (value: string) => (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void
export const Format = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('format');
```

The same erasure happens when using the type `FormFieldProperty(value: FormFieldOptions[K] | undefined)`

But an optional modifier `?` is conserved and is present on the returned function types:
Using `return function FormFieldProperty(value?: FormFieldOptions[K] | null) {`

```js
// const FormField: (value?: string) => (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void
export const FormField = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('name', 'propertyKey');
// const Label: (value?: string) => (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void
export const Label = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('label');
// const Format: (value?: string) => (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void
export const Format = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('format');
```

Why does `null` or `undefined` types get erased, but the optional modifier does not?

PS: My main objective here is getting `value` to be required if `defaultValue` is undefined, but be optional otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you think that the type is coerced, does your IDE show that? Using the first definition, you have to call the returned function (`FormFieldProperty`) as described by its signature, i.e. either with something of type `FormFieldOptions[K]` or with the value `null`; both of these are fine:

```js
export const Label = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('label');
Label("something");
Label(null);
```

If you want to achieve the behavior you described, you could use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
type InternalDecorator = (target: unknown, propertyKey: (string | symbol)) => void;

function FormFieldPropertyDecorator<K extends keyof FormFieldOptions>(
    option: K,
): (value: string) => InternalDecorator;
function FormFieldPropertyDecorator<K extends keyof FormFieldOptions>(
    option: K,
    defaultValue: FormFieldOptions[K] | 'propertyKey',
): (value?: string) => InternalDecorator;

function FormFieldPropertyDecorator<K extends keyof FormFieldOptions>(
    option: K,
    defaultValue?: FormFieldOptions[K] | 'propertyKey',
) {
    return function FormFieldProperty(value: FormFieldOptions[K]) {
        return function (target: unknown, propertyKey: string | symbol) {
            // ... Some reflect-metadata magic ...
        };
    };
}

export const Label1 = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('label');
Label1("something"); // OK
Label1();            // not OK

export const Label2 = FormFieldPropertyDecorator('label', "something");
Label2("something"); // OK
Label2();            // also OK
```

Comment: Yeah, it was just VS Code telling me the null type was removed, but it's actually ok
`undefined` seems to actually be removed for some reason  - but using function overloading solves my problem without having to use `| undefined`, thanks!